# how do we get the username of current logged in user in php?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to display username of user who is logged in on dropdown which contains option of settings, profile and logout.
here is login.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error[] = ''; // Variable To Store Error Message
require 'function/general.php';
require 'function/users.php';
include 'includes/db_connect.php';


if(empty($_POST)=== false){
$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true){
    $error[] = "you need to enter username and password";
}
else if(user_exists($username)=== false){
    $error[] = "cant find username . have you registerd";
}
else if (user_active($username)=== false) {
    $error[] = "havent activated account";

}else{
    $login = login($username,$password);
    if($login === false){
        $error[] = "invalide login credentials";
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['id'] = $login;

        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }


}


}

?>
```

here is users.php containing all the functions

```
<?php

function logged_in(){
    return(isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? true : false;

}

function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);


  return (mysql_result( mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `login` WHERE `username` ='$username' "), 0) == 1) ? true : false;

}

function user_active($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);


  return (mysql_result( mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `login` WHERE `username` ='$username' AND `active` = 1 "), 0) == 1) ? true : false;

}

function user_id_from_username($username){
    $username = sanitize ($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `login` WHERE `username` = '$username'"),0, 'id');
}

function login($username , $password){

    $id = user_id_from_username($username);

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `login` WHERE `username` ='$username' AND `password` = '$password'") , 0) == 1) ? $id : false;

}
```

here is where i want to show the name of logged in user

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'includes/bootstrap.html';


require 'function/general.php';
require 'function/users.php';
require 'includes/bootstrap.html';
?>

<script>
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

</script>
<!---------navbar --->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><h3>Utile</h3></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Browse Photos</a></li>

            </ul>

            <?php if (logged_in() === true) {
                ?>
                <!--  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a><a href="profile.php">Profile</a><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>

                -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> **here i want username** <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                            <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Setting</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <?php
                } else {
                    ?>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="register.php">Sign Up</a></li>
                <?php } ?>

                    <li><a href="registerpro.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Become Professional</button></a></li>

                </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Looking at your code.., I could guess you have followed phpacademy's login system.. Right?

Comment: yes... i am practising php login system

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed phpacademy's login system Then you must have the below functions

```
function user_data($user_id) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields = '`' .implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));

        return $data;
    }
}

function user_id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
}
```

Then you can get the username from

```
    $username= $user_data['username'];
```